# Adding a delete link for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have nested attributes in my show.erb and I create a blank nested attribute and show a grid of items with the blank at the bottom like so.

```
<%= form_for @question do |q| %>
  <% q.fields_for :answers, @question.answers do |l| %>
    <tr>

      <td><%= l.text_field :text %></td>
      <td><%= l.check_box :correct %></td>
      <td><%= l.text_field :imagename %></td>
      <td><%= l.number_field :x %></td>
      <td><%= l.number_field :y %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

  <tr>
        <td colspan=5 align=right><%= submit_tag '+' %>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

I want a link_to 'Destroy' to work but i'm getting `undefined method 'plural'` when i add this to the grid

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', l, :controller => "answer", :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why do you want to use a link? You can also use the destroy functionality in the nested attributes.

All you need to do is:

1. Add `:allow_destroy => true` in your `accepts_nested_attributes` definition
2. Add `:_allow_destroy` to your controller's strong params
3. Add `<%= l.check_box '_destroy' %>` to your template

That way it removes all the nested records with the check-box checked when saving the record.

Comment: For this to work, you must also add `:_destroy` to your `params.require()` in the controller for this to work. Add it in the accepted attributes for the associated model you need it for

Answer (score 10):

For those finding this from Google, while *technically* a delete checkbox might be the correct way, I think it is confusing - the only benefit is that it requires two clicks to delete (select box and hit update). It might be better to just ensure the delete is clear what is happening, and possibly add an easy way to get it back.

The following is to send the update to the server as ajax, to handle updating the page in a callback or js view file. Remove remote: true and it will work as a regular link.

```
# For my form I build a new object if it's missing,
# so I need to check that this is not a new nested attribute.
- unless question.answers.new_record?
  # Basically, I am sending over the fields that would be sent
  # by the _delete check box form being updated.
  = link_to "Delete", question_path(question.id, question: { answers_attributes: { id: question.answers.id, "_destroy" => true }}), remote: true, confirm: "Really delete?", method: :put
```

Comment: Yeah this works fine on a has_many relationship.
Also, to get a confirmation box you can add `, data: { confirm: 'You sure?' }` right after `method: :put`
The one thing I noticed (at least in my case) was that the item was deleted but the page didn't reload automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on has_many (no idea why it wouldn't work). Also added some notes from your comment about the confirm, and if you remove remote: true, it ought to work like a regular link and refresh the page - otherwise you have to handle that yourself.

Comment: I agree, the UX is really weird with a delete checkbox

Answer (score 1):

The variable you're using `l` isn't correct. When you yield from a `fields_for` block the block object is an instance of `FormBuilder` not an instance of the object itself. What url do you want the link to point to? Is it `Answers#destroy`? What id do you want to send to this action for it to identify what to destroy? A `link_to` isn't a form element. It's just a helper for an anchor tag. You need a url, not a form builder to build that link.

Is this going to be a list of answer forms? One for each answer? If so, you might want to loop through them instead of just using `fields_for`.

Hopefully this helps you get on the right track.

Comment: yes, i'm an idiot for not passing the model instead of the form builder