# Rails updating records via nested model forms and delete links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have two models- **Family** and **Person**:(Using Mongoid and Rails 3.2.13)

**family.rb**

```
attr_accessible :location  
has_many :persons
accepts_nested_attributes_for :persons
```

**person.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name
belongs_to :family
```

In the **FamiliesController** I have:

```
  def edit
   @family=Family.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @family=Family.find(params[:id])
    @family.update_attributes(params[:family])
  end
```

in the **edit.html.erb** for families controller:

```
<div class="container">
<%= simple_form_for @family do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.input :location %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :persons do |p| %>
      <%= p.input :name %>
    <%end%>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

But it **only updates the family attributes** and the persons attrubutes remains the same.

How do I update the Person's attributes as well?

Also I want to add a `delete` button for each person which will **delete the corresponding person.** How to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using params.permit somewhere in the controller?

Comment: it is used to filter which params are allowed , but if you are not using it then that is not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `persons_attributes` in `attr_accessible` # In `family.rb`

Comment: I have that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :persons`  then why do I need this?

Comment: Yeah that worked like charm. How about adding a seperate `delete` button for each person? See questions last line. **Will adding a simple delete button for each person do the work?**

Comment: B/c `accepts_nested_attributes_for :persons` only generate extra params for your nested model.

Comment: I think, `delete` button will be inside `persons_attributes`. It will work well.

Comment: **Update** Well I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7151191/1552570). But that gives me `No input found for checkbox` error.