# Ruby on Rails: Creating Delete Link Of Associated Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_model' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007fc5d1c46e60>
```

I'm trying to create a remove link to my associated image

```
<% @project.project_images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb) %>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= link_to "remove", image.photo, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

My Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images, allow_destroy: true
end

class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I believe my `image.photo` is wrong, but I'm not sure what it should be? I guess I should determine what the path is? But I don't have a routes for ProjectImages. I'm only saving the images through nested attributes. Do I really need to create a new routes? If so, what would it be?

EDIT (Adding Routes)

This is my routes:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'add_photos'
    post 'upload_photos'

  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your rake routes details.

Comment: @bipashant Hi, I added my routes, this is whats in my routes that pertains to projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @project.project_images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb) %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to "remove", project_path(@project.id, project: { project_images: { id: image.id, "_destroy" => true }}), remote: true, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :put %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hello! I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'project_image_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb005320c50>:0x007fb005308970>`

Comment: Please try this 

link_to "remove", project_path(@project.id, project: { project_images: { id: image.id, "_destroy" => true }}), remote: true, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :put

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150329/adding-a-delete-link-for-nested-attributes

Comment: I'm able to implement the code, but nothing has happened?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.. kinda... still need help though. So instead of `project_images:`, I did `project_images_attributes:` but it doesn't pop up a message, because of the `remote: true`. So I only know it was deleted, when I refresh. If I take this `remote: true` off, it gets redirected to the show page. I just want to keep it in the same page where this delete photo is. Its not confirming if I wanted to delete the photo or not.

Comment: Oh! just kidding, I didn't see the comment on that! Please change your answer so I can mark that correct!

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `.photo` in the link_to, because of it's not an object, this is a scope to define methods to work with `photo` (previews and so on):

```
<% @project.project_images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb) %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to "remove", image, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
  </div> <!-- maybe, you forgot it? -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: I removed it and now I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'project_image_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc5cfff1be8>:0x007fc5ce1db050>`

Comment: It isn't error of it's scope. Please show us line, which cause the error, plus show us your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: Its showing it on this line   `<%= link_to "remove", image, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>`. I also added my routes that pertains to projects