# Rails - How to delete associated attributes while updating a parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models namely `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetails` and:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invoice_details
```

Now an **User** has the ability to **edit** an **invoice**, so he can **remove** the **invoiceDetails attributes** from the **invoice**.
So how can I **delete** those **nested attributes** of the invoiceDetails model while updating the `invoice(parent)` model.

*I'm using AngularJS for client side.*

**The Update Action :**

```
  def update
    invoice_id = params[:id]
    invoice = Invoice.find(invoice_id)
    if invoice.update(invoice_params)
      render json: invoice, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: invoice.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def invoice_params
    invoice_params = params.require(:invoice).permit(:total_amount,:balance_amount, :customer_id, :totalTax, :totalDiscount, :bill_date,:company_id, { invoice_details: [:id,:invoice_id,:product_id,:quantity, :discount, :subtotal, :tax] })
    invoice_params[:invoiceDetails_attributes] = invoice_params.delete :invoice_details
    invoice_params.permit!
  end
```

The **Invoice Model**

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoiceDetails, inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoiceDetails
end
```

The **InvoiceDetails Model**

```
class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: You need to pass _destroy parameter true or false for every InvoiceDetail object.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer by giving an example

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is stalled on this, here is what I did. I added an attribute **is_hide** in **InvoiceDetails**(child) model.
When a user deletes an **InvoiceDetails** attribute, the **is_hide** property is set to **true**.

In the **Invoice**(parent) model, I used the **before_save** callback and iterated through the **InvoiceDetails** attributes and called **mark_for_destruction where is_hide = true**.

This is how my Invoice model looks :

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoiceDetails, inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoiceDetails

  before_save :mark_children_for_removal

  def mark_children_for_removal
    invoiceDetails.each do |child|
      child.mark_for_destruction if child.is_hide?
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

By now (not sure since when actually) this feature is built in and you can just use the `_destroy` attribute. Make sure to allow it in your parameters and the just add a checkbox to the nested form:

```
<%= nested_form.check_box '_destroy' %>
```

This will then remove all marked items on update/saving.

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151191/1595029